# Flow - Copying one Field Value to Another Field

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, fields, currency, sales

I just want to preface this by saying I am new to building out flows, so lots of trial and error, just wanting to guidance and advice!

- I am wanting to create a flow that copies a currency(numeric) field to another currency(numeric) field.
- I currently have when a record is created or updated as the configure trigger.
- I then added  the condition to when Recurring_Revenue__ is changed is true.

I know this if for when the value in the recurring revenue is changed it will then populate the 2nd currency field.

***However, I want it to automatically populate when a record is saved or created, not if it is changed. I am just not sure what the correct conditions would be for it.***

I also added the element "Update", and have the set field values for the opportunity record, for the ARR booking field to equal the Recurring Revenue field. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

[image: configure start part 1]
[image: configure start part 2]
[[image: configure update3]

Comment: so your goal is that every time the record is updated (or created), the value in `Annual_Recurring_Revenue__c` should be copied to `ARR_Booking__c` ?  If so, remove the entry condition in `Configure Start` altogether. Your flow will execute everytime and blindly copy the value, even if no change has occurred

Comment: This worked thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your scenario, since you would like to update the **same record**'s field, it is best for you to use the **Fast Field Updates** (as it is said to run typically faster; you can read about these 2 types [here](https://salesforcetime.com/2022/02/04/record-triggered-flow-before-save-vs-after-save/)) and as cropredy suggested in the comment of your original post above, you can remove the starting condition.

When you remove the starting condition, the flow will automatically run, every single time you **create** or **update** the record.

But I would personally advice you to make sure to update the value, only when the Recurring_Revenue__c field value changes or it is a new record. If not, you would be updating the record every single time for no reason.

So, remove the starting condition.

1. Put a decision element, and name the first outcome as *New Record/ARR Changed* and leave the default outcome as it is. (You can name them whatever you find it easy for you to understand).
2. For your *New Record/ARR Changed* branch, you can put the condition where, Record.Id does not equal RecordPrior.Id, which means the record is new. Because, as you can imagine, if you are updating a record, the record will have a prior Id right? + OR Condition it with + Record.Recurring_Revenue__c is changed True. 
    These condition means, if the record is new or if the record's Recurring_Revenue__c field is changed, then the flow will traverse/take/follow this path/branch.
   **The image below, is just an example**
   [image]
3. Finally add your update record element under this branch.
   [image]

In summary, this flow will run everytime you create/update record (of the object you specified in your starting condition). Then it will check if the Record is new OR Record's Recurring_Revenue__c is changed. If it is, then you can copy the field value using the update record element. If any of these conditions is not met, then the flow will follow the default outcome path and end (meaning it doesn't do anything).

I hope this help you to understand flow better. If you need more explanation on certain things I have mentioned above, please add a comment I will be more than happy to edit the post again to add more information!
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! I do have one question, I might have forgot to put this in my original post, but with this flow, I want to still be able to update the ARR booking field if needed. So for example, if the recurring revenue field = 22,000 and then it populates to ARR booking as $22,000, but we only had an ARR booking of = to 10,000. I want to still be able to update the ARR booking field to the $10,000 amount and it not always reflect the recurring revenue field amount. Hopefully that made sense!

Comment: Just to confirm, you would still like to edit the ARR booking field without changing the value in the Recurring_Revenue field right? If yes, then, based on the conditions  posted above as part of my answer, if you are creating a new record and have Recurring_Revenue = 22,000 and ARR = 10,000. It would not work and will change both the field values to 22,000. If you are updating a record and just changing the ARR value to 10,000. Then Recurring_Revenue field will be 22,000 and ARR = 10,000.

Comment: Hello! That is correct, I would still like to edit the ARR booking field without changing the reccuring revenue field. In some instances the Recurring Revenue and Arr Booking field should be the same value,this is why I wanted to create a flow where Recurring Revenue= ARR booking. However, sometimes the ARR booking field will be a different value that I still want to be able to change if I can? Is that possible? When I go to change it right now all it does is go back to the original value that is placed in the recurring revenue field. Let me know if that answered any of your questions!thanks!